# Get probability of each class in InceptionV3 fine tuning

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, transfer-learning

I want the probability of each class for a new image. Let's say like [0.1  0.2  0.7] for three classes. But `model.predict` only gives [0 0 1]. Is there any way to get the probability? Or is there any way to use the Sequential API of `keras` in InceptionV3 or Xception? Because I think in Sequential API it is possible. Again, if I use sigmoid activation for the last Dense layer, would that be helpful?

Edit: There was a bug in my code. Otherwise, `model.predict` returns probability.

Comment: Model.predict does return a probability for each class. Documentation is at https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model. Scroll down to predict and it clearly states it returns probabilities. Did you use cross-entropy whrn you compiled your model?

Comment: 0, 0, and 1 are probabiltiy values, its a misconception to think they are not

Comment: Thank you. I get it now. The problem was in another place and so I got values like this [0 0 1] all the time and thought the predict function always return values in that way.